# How much text can handle scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I have a sentiment analysis task and i need to specify how much data (in my case text) does scikit can handle. I have a corpus of 2500 opinions all ready tagged. I now that it´s a small corpus but my thesis advisor is asking me to specifically argue how many data does scikit learn can handle. My advisor has his doubts about python/scikit and she wants facts about how many text parameters, featues and stuff related can handle scikit-learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some timings for scikit-learn's document classification example on my machine (Python 2.7, NumPy 1.8.2, SciPy 0.13.3, scikit-learn 0.15.2, Intel Core i7-3540M laptop running on battery power). The dataset is twenty newsgroups; I've trimmed the output quite a bit.

```
$ python examples/document_classification_20newsgroups.py --all_categories
data loaded
11314 documents - 22.055MB (training set)
7532 documents - 13.801MB (test set)
20 categories

Extracting features from the training dataset using a sparse vectorizer
done in 2.849053s at 7.741MB/s
n_samples: 11314, n_features: 129792

Extracting features from the test dataset using the same vectorizer
done in 1.526641s at 9.040MB/s
n_samples: 7532, n_features: 129792

________________________________________________________________________________
Training: 
LinearSVC(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
     intercept_scaling=1, loss='l2', multi_class='ovr', penalty='l2',
     random_state=None, tol=0.001, verbose=0)
train time: 5.274s
test time:  0.033s
f1-score:   0.860
dimensionality: 129792
density: 1.000000

________________________________________________________________________________
Training: 
SGDClassifier(alpha=0.0001, class_weight=None, epsilon=0.1, eta0=0.0,
       fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15, learning_rate='optimal',
       loss='hinge', n_iter=50, n_jobs=1, penalty='l2', power_t=0.5,
       random_state=None, shuffle=False, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
train time: 3.521s
test time:  0.038s
f1-score:   0.857
dimensionality: 129792
density: 0.390184

________________________________________________________________________________
Training: 
MultinomialNB(alpha=0.01, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
train time: 0.161s
test time:  0.036s
f1-score:   0.836
dimensionality: 129792
density: 1.000000


________________________________________________________________________________
Training: 
BernoulliNB(alpha=0.01, binarize=0.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
train time: 0.167s
test time:  0.153s
f1-score:   0.761
dimensionality: 129792
density: 1.000000
```

Timings for dataset loading aren't shown, but it didn't take more than half a second; the input is a zipfile containing texts. "Extracting features" includes tokenization and stopword filtering. So in all, I can load up 18.8k documents and train a naive Bayes classifier on 11k of them in five seconds, or an SVM in ten seconds. That means solving a 20×130k dimensional optimization problem.

I advise you to re-run this example on your machine, because the actual time taken depends on a lot of factors including the speed of the disk.

[Disclaimer: I'm one of the scikit-learn developers.]

Comment: Thank you, as i said it before i want to use scikit for my thesis. What about SVM algorithm how many features can be passed on it?

Comment: @anon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326699/how-many-features-can-scikit-learn-handle

Answer (score 0):

[This Scikit page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html) may provide some answers if you are experiencing some issues with the amount of data that you are trying to load.

As stated in your other question on data size [concerning Weka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979182/how-much-text-can-weka-handle), I agree with ealdent that your dataset does seem small (unless you have an exceptionally large number of features) and it should not be a problem to load a dataset of this size into memory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sure, i didn´t consider that number of features. What about that?, how many features can handle scikit?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326699/how-many-features-can-scikit-learn-handle) may help you with that question.

Comment: So SVM in scikit is not the best option?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not about `scikit-learn`, it's about what algorithms you want to use. Most of `scikit-learn`'s internals are implemented in `C` or `Fortran`, so it's quite efficient. For example, `scikit-learn` random forest is the fastest out there ([see page 116 in this link](http://www.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/%7Eglouppe/pdf/phd-thesis.pdf)). For converting text to vectors, I have had success on a dataset of 50k documents running on my desktop in a couple of seconds and a few GB of memory. You can do even better than that if you are willing to use a hashing vectoriser (in exchange for not being able to interpret the feature vocabulary). In terms of classifiers, Naive Bayes takes `O(NVC)` time where `N` is the number of documents, `V` is the number of features and `C` is the number of classes. Non-linear SVM may give you better results, but will take **much** longer. If you start storing stuff in dense numpy matrices (as opposed to sparse scipy ones) you are much more likely to run out memory.

Comment: I really understand that most of the code of scikit is in C, but my advisor is clunged on using weka which most of it´s code is writen in java. He told me to argue why scikit is a better tool which clearly it´s better than weka. How can i argue him more formally?